# How do I require one of three values be checked in Laravel validation?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a list of checkboxes that look like this here:

[image]

The full list is here:

[image]

I am using the section_id to group them into columns / rows. And here is the code for the input:

```
    <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input class="{{ $screen->section->slug }}"
                   type="checkbox"
                   value="{{ $screen->id }}"
                   name="screens[]"{{
              isset($selected) && in_array($screen->id, $selected)
              ? ' checked'
              : ''
            }}><span class="fa fa-check"></span>{{ $screen->name }}
          </label>
        </div>
```

So far so good.

The part I am having trouble with is that I need to require that at least one of checkboxes under required for standard biometrics be checked.

How can I validate this?

I have an EventRequest file that handles all of my validation and I was thinking something like:

```
'screens.*' => 'nullable|integer|exists:screens,id|max:255|required_without_all:5,6,7',
```

That code doesn't work but I hope that clearly explains that I need to make sure one of those 3 ids is checked. Or I need to require that there be at least one item from the section_id two present in the array. Thoughts on how to do this?

```
public function rules(Request $request) : array
{
    return [
        ...
        'screens.*' => 'nullable|integer|exists:screens,id|max:255',
        ...
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a custom validation rule?

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Here is a sample validator class from a verification code validator I once made. `$validator` has access to the rest of the form data.

I registered it in a service provider using `Validator::extend()`

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Validators;


use App\PendingUserActivation;


/**
 * Class ActivationTokenExists
 *
 * @package \App\Auth\Rules
 */
class VerificationCodeValidator implements ValidatorInterface
{



public function passes($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{

    $verification_code = $validator->getData()['verification_code'];
    $token = $validator->getData()['token'];
    return $this->verify($token, $verification_code);
}

/**
 * @param $userToken
 * @param $verification_code
 * @return bool
 */
public function verify($userToken, $verification_code)
{
    $passes = PendingUserActivation::where('token', $userToken)
        ->where('verification_code', $verification_code)
        ->exists();

    return $passes;
}


/** @return string */
public static function getMessage()
{
    return 'We were unable to activate an account using the :attribute provided. Please try again.';
}

/** @return string */
public static function getName()
{
   return 'verification_code_valid';
}
}
```